# Why can't I create a subscription outside of useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand why the following code doesn't work (in some cases, the event firing and calling setState will have no effect on the react component at all) unless I put the call to subscribe inside a useEffect function:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  customSubscription.subscribe(someEvent, () => setState(true);
  return <div>{state}</div>;
}
```

In particular I'm wondering why this doesn't work after the first render? I realize that after more than one render, the subscription would get created multiple times. But why doesn't this work even when number of renders = 1?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It could be that the first callback is invoked synchronously. React doesn't like synchronous calls to `setState()`. Set a breakpoint in the callback to the subscribe method, and see if `MyComponent` is in the stack trace. If so, that's why it doesn't work. Also make sure you return `customSubscription.subscribe()` from your `useEffect()` so that the cleanup will unsubscribe your observable.

Comment: Interestingly I can no longer reproduce it... But to answer your comment: I am triggering the someEvent event via calling a function from the console that hooks into customSubscription. So I don't think it's possible that it's firing synchronously from MyComponent.

Comment: In any case, even if you could get it working this way, as you already pointed out it should be in a `useEffect()` to prevent the memory leaks created by subscribing multiple times without unsubscribing.

Comment: Yep - I'm asking this question out of pure curiosity here, because I want to better understand what's going on. I was able to reproduce it again. Here's the stack trace when I break on the line that runs setState. https://imgur.com/a/Xc4n1nr

Comment: Ok so interesting finding. In the debugger (breaking on same line), if I hover over setState I see: `bound dispatchAction ƒ bound dispatchAction()` when called from useEffect, and otherwise I see: `(anonymous) react_devtools_backend.js:24 ƒ anonymous()`

This would imply it's somehow related to the react dev tools extension? Odd

Comment: The code that the react_devtools_backend.js:24 points to is:

`useState: function(e) {
            var t = f();
            return e = null !== t ? t.memoizedState : "function" == typeof e ? e() : e,
            u.push({
                primitive: "State",
                stackError: Error(),
                value: e
            }),
            [e, function() {}
            ]
        },`

Which indeed is an empty setState function.

Comment: Looks like this is the original code it points to: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b779dd51e87b92e13001b5deac4887bb4984ecf2/packages/react-debug-tools/src/ReactDebugHooks.js#L130